# C# to Java Code

Tags: c#, java, asp.net, xml, servlets

I have a small piece of code I was given in C#:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try{
        string sFind = Request.QueryString["F"];
        string sFindBy = Request.QueryString["FB"];

        Response.ContentType = "text/xml";
        //Simulate Resonse (throw exeption on error) -------------------------------->

        XmlDocument docRet = new XmlDocument();
        XmlElement docElement = (XmlElement)docRet.AppendChild(docRet.CreateElement("Request"));
        generateResponseParamss(docElement, "Language", "heb");
        generateResponseParamss(docElement, "IMTSI", "972.001.000000081");
        generateResponseParamss(docElement, "Mobile", "0544490540");
        generateResponseParamss(docElement, "Email", "gadi.email@gmail.com");
        generateResponseParamss(docElement, "FirstName", "גדי");
        generateResponseParamss(docElement, "LastName", "גדיגדי");

        docRet.Save(Response.OutputStream);

        }catch(Exception ex){
            ShowErrorAsXml(Response, ex);
        }
    }

    public void generateResponseParamss(XmlElement docElement, string sParamsName, string sParamsValue)
    {
        XmlElement newNode = (XmlElement)docElement.AppendChild(docElement.OwnerDocument.CreateElement("Param"));
        newNode.SetAttribute("Name", sParamsName);
        newNode.SetAttribute("Value", sParamsValue);
    }
```

And I would like to turn this code to Java, I think I need to create a servlet that receives parameter through the URL line ("GET"), but the C# code line that I'm most dificult with is:

```
docRet.Save(Response.OutputStream);
```

Which command do the same in Java.

Comment: This is what you are looking for http://www.petefreitag.com/item/445.cfm

Comment: Sorry still doesn't understand how to "send" the created xml throught the servlet's response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Look at this tutorial.](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JAXPXSLT4.html#wp64614) Search for `StreamResult result = new StreamResult(System.out);`.

Change that line to have `new StreamResult(new PrintStream(response.getOutputStream()));`

Comment: Does the C# Page_Load method equivalent to doGet of the Java Servlet?

Comment: Yes, usually gets called for GET requests

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do that. What class are you using for storing the xml response?

Comment: Then I would agree to Grrrrr's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9276769/c-sharp-to-java-code/9277088#9277088). But if I had just text data to output, I would prefer PrintWriter rather than the PrintStream, because in case of PrintStream, the character encoding depends on platform.
`PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
StreamResult streamResult = new StreamResult(out);`